# Is there a 64 bit SCC provider for ClearCase?

Tags: version-control

Just got Slick Edit 16, 64 bit installed, and I use ClearCase for version control.  Normally, I have used the SCC provider to do my work, but I'm on a 64 bit OS now, and would really like the power of a native 64 bit program on my OS.  Unfortunately it looks like Slick Edit also needs a 64 bit SCC provider, and my default installation of ClearCase doesn't have it.

Is there a 64 bit SCC provider for ClearCase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this thread, no, there isn't a 64-bit version of the SCM provider packaged with ClearCase.

> Looks like it's a 32-bit DLL: C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\ccscc.dll

A [RFE (Request For Enhancement #9779) has been opened](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=9779) (you need an IBM account to see it), and I just voted for it.

> would like a 64-bit DLL available `C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\ccscc.dll`
>
> Use case: SlickEdit V15 was functional on Win7/64-bit environment, but V16 is not functional.

Comment: This is what I eventually found, too.  Thanks for voting :)